# Wincache log in Azure

Tags: php, azure-web-app-service, wincache

How can I see the wincache log in my Azure web app running PHP 7.x? I can see that there is one but not how to view it. For instance if wincache_ucache_set returns an error I want to know why, all it does is return FALSE.